Passing CSS From Parent to Child in React/ React Native
This is my parent component:
  <View style={[BookStyles.memberButtonContainer, SpaceStyles.mt(20)]}>
    <Button color={'darkGray'}text="Learn more" />
  </View>

This is the child component
export const Button = ({ color = 'dark' => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      {loading && <ActivityIndicator color={LoadingColors[color]} />}
         <Text style={ButtonStyles.text(color)}>{text}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

What I want to do is pass styles from the parent to the child component. Something like:
{fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 500} and apply it to Text element which currently has style={ButtonStyles.text(color).
I have tried passing objects and variables. I couldn't get it to work.
What is the way to do this?
